# C++ on VS Code . Output is not coming on the integrated terminal

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I wrote a simple C++ program in VSCode. It is compiling without any issues, but the output is not visible on the VSCode integrated terminal. If I open a separate terminal externally using cmd, I can get the output. Can someone explain this behavior?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "Weclcome";
    return 0;
    
}
```

[image: vscode screenshot]

Comment: Look at the debug console.

Comment: Can you also add the command you have used to compile?

Comment: What happens if you `cout << "Weclcome" << std::endl;`

Comment: I have used the front end options Terminal  --> Runbuild task and there are 2 compile options g++ or gcc

Comment: @drescherjm still the same

Comment: execute `echo hello` on the integrated terminal and let us know if it outputs correctly